# Linq: GroupBy not show result for the .Include clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Why in the result "Titolare" is null?
If I don't use `GroupBy`, "Titolare" has value.
Thank you.

```
var ben = context.Benefici.Include("Titolare").Include("Titolare.ComuneDomicilio")
                    .Where(b => !b.Titolare.SD1_DAT_DECESSO.HasValue)                                                                                                         
                    .OrderByDescending(b => b.SDB_DAT_INIZIO)
                    .GroupBy(b => b.SDB_CODDIS)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(b => b.First())                        
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: please share some info about data itself

Comment: Please share the models as we can't imagine what `b.SDB_CODDIS` could possible be

Comment: Why are you calling `ToList` twice?

Comment: @Charlieface: because Select is not possible after GroupBy and I need to have a list as a final result

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `GroupBy` limitation - you cannot get grouped items using LINQ to Entities. It should be fixed in EF Core 6.

To get first item of the group, you have to rewrite your query. It is mimic of what will be generated by EF Core 6:

```cs
var itemsQuery = context.Benefici
    .Where(b => !b.Titolare.SD1_DAT_DECESSO.HasValue);                                                                                                       

var benQuery = 
    from u in itemsQuery.Select(b => new { b.SDB_CODDIS }).Distinct()
    join b in itemsQuery
        .Include(x => x.Titolare.ComuneDomicilio)
        .Where(x => x.SDB_CODDIS == u.SDB_CODDIS)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.SDB_DAT_INIZIO)
        .Take(1)
    select b;

var ben = benQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, but Visual Studio show an error: `System.Linq.IQueryable<T>` not contains definition for `.Include`. Probably a using directive or assembly reference is missing

Comment: So use your Includes with strings.